# calling a function in a separate script from a class that is not a member of a class

Tags: python, class, function, structure

I have program with two files; main.py that has my main logic and class.py which has my classes.  My problem is that I can't figure out how to call a function in main.py from a function in a class in class.py.  Here's a simple example:

in class1.py

```
class Class1: 

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def main_logic(self):
        if self.value == 'y':
            return self.value
        else:
            self.value == 'n':
                #main()??   How would I call main() in main.py?
```

in main.py

```
def display1():  
    print('Main Menu')

def main():
    create_obj = Class1(value1)
    new_object = Class1.main_logic()
    if new_object == 'y':
        display1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Of course if there is a better way to structure something like this I could use some help there as well.

Comment: Why is the function you are calling in main as it seams that all users of Class1 will need it?

Comment: I tried to simplify the example.  In this case, yes, I could add main() to Class1.  I guess what I am really asking is how to call a function that is not in a class and in a seperate file from a function that is in a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally not the best method of writing code, but you could: `import main; main.display1()` (or `import whateverTHEfileNAMEis` if its not main.py) like so:

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def main_logic(self):
        if self.value == 'y':
            return self.value
        else:
            self.value == 'n':
                import main
                main.display1()
```

Comment: Thanks!  Would a better way be to have main() and display1() in a class? Any other suggestions on how this should be properly structured?

Comment: Yea, I would just put display1() in the same file as Class1 (doesnt have to be a method of Class1 though) and leave main() in main.py.